# jQuery how do I override input text value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I face a problem to override the table cell value which is input box,
I want to do some calculation based on previous cell , 
but also want to override when user enter via input text

If I do both at the same time , the auto calculation done but entered value gone

```
var otherAllowanceX;
      var otherAllowance = tr.find($('input[name="other_allowance[]"]')).val() || otherAllowanceX;
      if(otherAllowance ==''){
              if (parseFloat(basicPay) >= 5500 ) 
              {
                //var pTax  = 300;
                 otherAllowanceX = parseFloat((parseFloat(1624.02)/CURR_MONTH_DAYS)*noOfDays);
                 tr.find('input[name="other_allowance[]"]').val(otherAllowanceX);
              } 
              else 
              {
               // var  Allowance = 245.67;
                otherAllowanceX = parseFloat((parseFloat(245.67)/CURR_MONTH_DAYS)*noOfDays);
                tr.find('input[name="other_allowance[]"]').val(otherAllowanceX);
              }
        }


    console.log(":::: Other AllowanceX "+otherAllowanceX+" :::: Other Allowance"+otherAllowance);
```

Table field

```
<td><input type="text" class="cal form-control" name="other_allowance[]" placeholder="Other Allowance" value="0"></td>
```

I want to make input box editable and when its value entered skip calculation

Comment: `parseFloat((parseFloat(1624.02)/CURR_MONTH_DAYS)*noOfDays)` - What's the reason for calling `parseFloat()` on a number (twice)? O.o

Comment: ok but nothing change